# core data displaying to-many relationship data in second view controller

Tags: iphone, core-data

My core data model looks like this 2 entities with the 1st TableViewController displaying the districts, and when user selected the district, it pushes to the 2nd view and display the schools in that district.   I have the 1st TableViewController with the NSFetchedResultController setup and display correctly entityForName @"District" , but I am currently stuck and failing on pushing the data to the 2nd view controller which has a custom table cell controller.

**District**
name
province
__
schools <--- to-many relationship ---->> indistrict

**School**
name
phone
image
__
indistrict  <<--- to-one relationship ---> schools

It would be great if anyone could show me the code example on how to pass the data to the 2nd view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You just pass the selected school data to second view controller, you then use the same search but with

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"district.school.name == %@", school.name]
```

in your NSPredicate.